Gitversion no bump in major/minor version
I am trying to configure Gitversion to bump major version with configuration:
mode: Mainline
next-version: 1.0.0
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'
patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
branches: {}
ignore:
sha: []
merge-message-formats: {}

Though I pass commit message with prefix "breaking change", i see change only on patch version, i.e. 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 instead of 2.0.0. why this is not working.
I also tried to bump major version using branch names "featue/" which didnt work either.
mode: Mainline
branches:
  master:
    increment: Patch
  feature/*:
    increment: Major
    regex: ^feature\/.*
    source-branches: ['master']
  release/*:
    increment: Major
    regex: ^release\/.*
    source-branches: ['master']
  hotfix/*:
    increment: Patch
    regex: ^hotfix\/.*
    source-branches: ['master']

In the gitversion documentation I see one of the version mode "Manual Deployment" but nothing about "Mainline". Are these both same.
Tried to apply the quoted configurations with an expectation to control major/minor numbers using commit messages or branch names.
Everytime, I see change only on patch number, i.e. 1.0.0 to 1.0.1, 1.0.2 and so on.
